# MongoDB: Log rotate does not appear to be working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-18.04, logrotate

I tried to set up log rotation on a small VPS sever using the instructions here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/rotate-log-files/.

However, I see that the mongodb log file is very large (> 1GB) and has not been transitioned since I tried to set up rotation.  Here's what I have in my `mongodb.conf` file:

```
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
logappend=true
smallfiles = true
logRotate=reopen
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
journal=true
replSet = rs0
oplogSize = 100
```

When I run `db._adminCommand( {getCmdLineOpts: 1})`, I see this under systemLog:

```
"systemLog" : {
    "destination" : "file",
    "logAppend" : true,
    "logRotate" : "reopen",
    "path" : "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log"
}
```

I was previously using the `mongod` service as opposed to `mongodb`, which I'm currently using.  It appears that rotation was working for `mongod` (even though I don't recall setting it up), because there are some older log files which are of equal size, meaning that the rotation was happening exactly when the file got too large rather than at scheduled intervals, and I'd like it to keep working like it previously was.  Looking at the `mongod.conf` file, here is the configuration:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
```

First of all, I'm not sure why the syntax is different.  I've also run the `db.runCommand( { logRotate : 1 } )` command inside mongo, although I believe that's a one time rotation.  From the `mongodb.conf` file and the command line options, I would have thought it should work.  Is there anything else I should add?

Answer (score 0):

`logrotate: reopen` means that it will keep opening the same log file, and you should rotate the log using an external tool. See [Log Rotation with --logRotate reopen](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/rotate-log-files/#log-rotation-with-logrotate-reopen).

Note the caveat with `reopen` in the linked page:

- You must use the `--logappend` option with `--logRotate reopen`.
- You should rename the log file using an external process, following the typical Linux/Unix log rotate behavior.

If you want to rotate the log once it gets to a certain size, you can use `reopen` in conjunction with the [logrotate utility](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/logrotate/logrotate.8.en.html) which should be present in most Linux distributions. See the manual/tutorial on your specific distribution on the correct settings for the logrotate utility. Here's some examples: [How to setup log rotation for MongoDB properly](https://www.zoonman.com/blog/mongodb-logrotated/), and [Mongodb - proper way to rotate logs](https://serverfault.com/questions/540423/mongodb-proper-way-to-rotate-logs).

If you rather MongoDB to rotate the logs for you, you should use `logrotate: rename`. This will rename the old log file, then create a new one every server restart. See [Default Log Rotation Behavior](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/rotate-log-files/#default-log-rotation-behavior).

Comment: Okay, I did see something like the two links about setting up rotation.  What makes me nervous are the `postrotate` commands.  They seem to be different for every example.  Looking at the example at https://www.zoonman.com/blog/mongodb-logrotated/ I don't see a `/var/run/mongodb.pid` file in that directory.  I think I should be able to replace that command with `kill -SIGUSR1 $(pgrep mongod)` correct?  Also, this will definitely rotate automatically when it gets too large or will it only check once per day?